# KeyError: '\n' Python, String Mutation Generator

Tags: python

Hi I've created some code which prints password mutations. However, I'm having trouble getting it to read multiple passwords from a text file with lots of common passwords in there. Here is my code:

```
from itertools import product
for password in commonpasswords:
    allPossible = list(mapping[letter] for letter in password)
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting an error, I essentially want it to read each entry in the text file 1 line at a time, perform as many mutations of it as possible then move onto the next one. The file contains only lower case words and each entry is on a separate line. Thanks.

EDIT: I'm also having trouble creating the total, I've added this code at the end of the loop, removing both the print functions:

```
total = total + len(allPossible)
print(total)
```

However this doesn't seem to work, the total number of mutations is the number I'm after. Thanks.

Comment: well looks like it reads the lines WITH the newlines...

Comment: Please post the Traceback.

Comment: New doubts are better if asked as a new question, to gather more people to answer

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll delete this question and start a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you read any line from a file, It automatically picks up the `\n` character ate the end. Thus you will have to strip the `\n` off before. 
Add a line, `password.strip('\n')` at the start of your loop like

```
for password in commonpasswords:
    password = password.strip('\n')
```

(Or as it is always the last word you can do `password[:-1]` as in `allPossible = list(product(*([letter] + mapping[letter] for letter in password[:-1)))`)

Comment: `rstrip` would be better

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The other answer contained `rstrip` so didn't post. :(

Answer (score 2):

```
for password in commonpasswords:
    password = password.rstrip('\n')
```